# How does Visual Studio and Github work together?

Tags: c++, github, organization

For example: I'm making an SFML game and I want to store my project on GitHub so my team members can have access to it. Since its made in Visual Studio does that mean I need to include: Solution file and .vcxproj file?

Also, I've seen projects on GitHub have a "src" folder to organize their repository, since mine was created in Visual Studio does that mean I need to rename my folder that is named after my project to "src" and reupload it? Or are people doing some sort of organization trick I'm missing?

Since the game is SFML, all my binaries (.dll) files are just thrown into my main folder of the project, I'd much prefer to throw them all into their respective folder, but if someone downloads my project does that mean they need to pull it out of that folder and throw it into the project file? (That way visual studio can find them)

TLDR: I'm having trouble organizing my GitHub repo with a Visual Studio C++ Project.

Comment: I use CMake with out of source building and keep all generated files like Visual Studio project files, compiled output, dlls ... out of the github repository completely. You can however use a .gitignore file to avoid uploading these files if you don't use out of source building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since its made in Visual Studio does that mean I need to include:
>   Solution file and .vcxproj file?

Yes, you'll need to include solution and project files. You can see which files you can ignore at [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io/api/c++,visualstudio). Or, you can use cmake.

> I'd much prefer to throw them all into their respective folder, but if
>   someone downloads my project does that mean they need to pull it out
>   of that folder and throw it into the project file?

Yes, each collaborator will have to download libraries and make it available to project on their end. And if you have lots of libraries and libraries depending on other libraries, updating them can be painful.

I use cmake and vcpkg. It isn't as straight forward as keeping libraries in project folder but requires reasonable effort for keeping project organized and clean. I'll recommend this approach.